# NSUserdefaults are not working correctly in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have an app which shows the settings page ONCE! This is when it is first download from the app store. After that then it goes to the main page only.

but when you swipe the app when you double click the iPhone button and remove the app then it goes back to the settings page.

Here is some code from my app

didfinishwithOptions

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SettingsShown"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"ShowBackButton"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];

}



if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SettingsShown"] == NO)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
}
```

then I have put

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
    NSLog(@"Application is terminated");
}
```

this should run when you swipe the application when you double click on the iPhone button. but it isn't setting the user default to 0 because it is running the settings page again from didfinishwithoptions.  Can anyone advise ?

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate:` is not called in most apps.

Comment: ok, so how do i do it, so that the settings page does not show after you swipe the application away ? Most apps carry on from where they are after being swiped off.

Comment: Most apps save their state when they enter the background incase the app is terminated while suspended.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to show the settings every time the App was quit completely? If so, why?

Comment: Based on your description, I think you have some logic issues. You say you want it to only show the very first time (when `SettingsShown` bool is `NO`) but then you set the bool back to `NO` in your app terminate method.

Answer (score 3):

Any value put into `NSUserDefaults` is not necessarily written instantly. If you app, for instance, terminates in some unusual way, there is no guarantee, the data will be written.

You can force the system to write to the `NSUserDefaults`, using synchronize:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize):

> Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.
>   Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

There is a minor performance penalty doing so.